# Excel-like vertical and horizontal headers for android

Tags: android, view, header

I need to have excel-like headers.
It means, that it has vertical headers (fixed horizontally), which can be scrolled vertically, and horizontal headers (fixed vertically), which can be scrolled horizontally.
The contents should be scrollable both vertically and horizontally.

To make it clear, I tried to 'draw' here.

```
                  hor_header1 | hor_header2  | hor_header3 | .......
ver_header1  |  content1_1    | content1_2   | content1_3   | ...........
ver_header2  |  content2_1    | content2_2   | content2_3   | ........
ver_header3  |  content3_1    | content3_2   | content3_3   | ...........
.......      |   ...........  | ..........   | ...........
```

So ver_header1,2,3 should be sticky when I scroll horizontally, and hor_header1,2,3 should be sticky when I scroll vertically

How could I achieve this? Is it possible in android???

Thanks before.

Heru

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into Android that supports bi-directional scrolling, let alone your notion of headers. It is possible to write this yourself, but I suspect it will involve a fair bit of work.